# Hearing the "wrong" megilla reading

Tags: halacha-theory, megillat-esther, time-zone

During the coronavirus year, there was an allowance made (according to [certain](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Halachot_Related_to_Coronavirus/COVID-19_Pandemic#cite_note-34) opinions) for people to hear the megillah via Zoom. [This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/111925/purim-2020-skype-megilla-leining-recommendation) question mentions that particular arrangement.

What would be the ruling (hypothetically) were one to hear the evening megillah via Zoom, but the one reading it was reading what was for him the morning reading? If I "tuned in" to a shul in Hong Kong, 13 hours ahead of me, they might be reading an 8AM reading while I need a 7PM reading?

The reverse can also be asked (if someone at 8AM in Hong Kong listened to the 7PM reading in New York). The person reading has in mind to be motzi people listening, but motzi them (I would assume) for THAT particular reading.

Are the two part of a single mitzvah so either would suffice for either part of the obligation? Or does the fact that the [night](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90009/when-is-the-main-mitzvah-of-hearing-the-megillah) reading is 'lesser' mean that this hypothetical would only work in one time-direction?

Note - I'm not sure if this same situation can occur with any other mitzvah (two time bound iterations close enough in time that being involved in the "wrong" one could satisfy the other); if you know of others, please let me know. All the ones I thought of are dissimilar enough for me not to list them.

Comment: You could imagine two people on opposite sides of the halachic dateline (whichever opinion you follow for where it is) where one needs to make kiddush for YT rishon and the other for YT sheini.  No zoom needed.

Comment: Or kind of similar would be an Israeli and a ben chutz laaretz who both need to say על נטילת לולב on the second day

Comment: How about a ben krach reading after plag to a ben ir? In any event, poskim clearly never talked about such cases and anyone modern will hence tell you we don't know and you shouldn't do it.

Comment: Someone listening to a chazzan repeating the mincha amidah, with the intent to fulfill his own arvit amidah (after plag hamincha)